# String.Format anomaly

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I'm probably a great big idiot for not seeing something extremely obvious, but I don't know what I can check now.

The problem is this. If I have this code

```
decimal d = 45550M;
string s = string.Format("{0}", d);
```

the result sometimes is `"45550,00"` instead of `"45550"`.
And I don't know what causes this.

What can I check? What can cause String.Format to not always behave the same?

Comment: Are you getting different results with the same input? On the same machine?

Comment: What means _sometimes_, early in the morning first, late at night second?

Comment: @JonB Yes, I am. If I put this at the very beginning of the program, the result is as expected, but sometime during its run, after having done some culture-specific I/O, String.Format starts to think that doing two decimals should be the default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [decimal value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a certain scaling factor. Depending on the operations you perform on a decimal value, the scaling factor can change.

> A decimal number is a floating-point value that consists of a sign, a numeric value where each digit in the value ranges from 0 to 9, and a scaling factor that indicates the position of a floating decimal point that separates the integral and fractional parts of the numeric value.

Unless you specify a number of decimal places, the number of decimal places defaults to match the scaling factor of the decimal value.

> The scaling factor also preserves any trailing zeroes in a Decimal number. Trailing zeroes do not affect the value of a Decimal number in arithmetic or comparison operations. However, **trailing zeroes can be revealed** by the ToString method if an appropriate format string is applied.

*Example:*

```
var x = 100m;
var y = x * 1.00m;

string s1 = string.Format("{0}", x); // "100"
string s2 = string.Format("{0}", y); // "100.00"
```

Comment: Oh man. I didn't know that at all. And how long have I been programming in C#? Six years; you'd expect that I'd encountered that long ago. But here I was checking if `d==decimal.Floor(d)` and so on. Oh well. Thanks for teaching me something new!

Answer (score 3):

The result will vary from machine to machine, because you are not specifying an explicit culture to use for the formatting, so the runtime will use the current thread culture, which will really be the one configured on the machine.

Comment: If that were true, the results would be consistent. But it only starts happening after doing a number of calculations, user I/O etc. And I'm pretty sure I'm not changing the global culture info of the program

Answer (score 2):

`string.Format("{0:0}", d);` should always output 0 decimals ("45550")

Comment: No, that's not what I want, I don't want the output rounded to whole numbers.